# Disable adding fragment to backstack in Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Suppose i have 4 fragments: A, B, C, X, and I can navigate between them in this way:

```
... -> A -> C -> X    and ... -> B -> C -> X
```

But when I'm in fragment X call `mNavController.navigateUp()` I want skip fragment C and go to fragment A or B. What I need to do?

UPD: I need solution only for Navigation Architecture Component https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Given `R.id.fragmentC` is the name of C destination, from X destination, you can do the following:

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentC, true);
```

This should pop all destinations off the stack until before C, and leave either A or B on top of the stack.

Comment: That is ok if you are navigating programmatically what if you're using bottomNavigation view to navigate to other fragments

Comment: @Robotec did you find a solution to this error via bottom navigation?

Comment: This is not the same thing as disabling adding specific fragment to backstack with popping them all.

Answer (score 30):

Alternatively you could use `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` attributes in navigation `xml` resource to cleanup back stack automatically when perform certain transactions, so back / up button will bring your user to the root fragment.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.package.Fragment1"
    android:label="Fragment 1">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
        app:destination="@id/fragment2"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragment1"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true / false" />

</fragment>
```

Comment: Simple and sophisticated!

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @bentesha this works in this way that it will pop fragments until fragmentC inclusively.

You can also achieve this as below:

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, false);
```

OR

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentB, false);
```

And this will pop up to fragmentA/fragmentB exclusively, I think it's most descriptive way for yourself and for others to understand.

Comment: What if there were dynamically changing locations the user could navigate in from? (for example, there are destinations A, B, X, Y, Z. How could we identify which one was navigated from in order to navigate back to it dynamically?