# Android navigation component exclude fragment from back stack

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I need to exclude `Fragment` from back stack.
I know there are many questions here regarding this issue, but I cousin't find an answer to my issue.
Let's say I have `Fragment` A and `Fragment` B. `Fragment` A is move to `Fragment` B and `Fragment` B open another `Activity`. What I need is when I click back from that `Activity` go back to Fragment A.

***Below is my XML of the graph:***

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_liabilities_fragment"
        android:name="liabilities.liabilities_list_fragment.view.LiabilitiesListFragment"
        android:label="LiabilitiesListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_liabilities_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_liabilities_fragment_to_nav_missing_liability_details_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_missing_liability_details_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_liabilities_fragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false"
            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_missing_liability_details_fragment"
        android:name="ui.flow.lobby.liabilities.missing_liability_details.view.MissingDetailsLiabilityFragment"
        android:label="MissingDetailsLiabilityFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_missing_details_liability">

        <argument
            android:name="extra_data"
            app:argType="android.repository.network.model.response.liabilities.LiabilityModel" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533721/disable-adding-fragment-to-backstack-in-navigation-architecture-component

Comment: @memres Already tried this. not working. Thanks anyway.